# Android Navigation Component: Issues with animations and backstack when returning to prior fragment via direction

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

Here's my scenario, boiled down as much as possible:

I have 2 fragments, A and B. There's a circular path between A and B on the graph, so A has a button that navigates to B, and B has a button to navigate to A. I'm having two issues with this scenario.

1. I'm playing an animation (a simple modal "slide up" where B slides up ontop of A) when launching B. It plays fine forwards (launching B) and back (pressing back). I would like it to play the exit animation when I navigate back to A as well (same animation as if I had pressed the back button, but on the fragment transaction). I can get an enter animation to play on A, but no exit animation will play on B.
2. The backstack. When navigating back to A, I don't want B or the first instance of A to remain on the backstack.

I've put together a sample project that demonstrates this issue: https://github.com/Morrodin/animtest

I'll include my graph directly in this post as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/FirstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/FirstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.FirstFragment"
        android:label="@string/first_fragment_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/SecondFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_up"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/none"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/none"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_down" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/SecondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.SecondFragment"
        android:label="@string/second_fragment_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment"
            app:destination="@id/FirstFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/none"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_down"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/none"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_down" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Comment: Adding `app:destination` to an action means you are creating a whole new instance of that destination - that's not a pop at all. Is there a reason you aren't just using `popBackStack()` in your button?

Comment: I was hoping to send information back along the bundle. Imagine that SecondFragment is a picker of some kind, and I'm trying to send that back to FirstFragment.

I ended up just using an eventbus and `popBackStack` as you mentioned, but it would be nice to not have to rely on something like the event bus.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the [APIs specifically designed to return a result to the previous destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result)?